# clamAV whitelist inoperative on Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: 14.04, clamav

After installing ClamAV on a dual boot WinXP//LxTrusty and setting up a daily virus-db update and scan of /home, I noticed a LOT of false positives. They are of the type:

```
  - PUA.Script.PDF.EmbeddedJS ...
  - PUA.OLE.EmbeddedPDF ...
  - PUA.Win32.Packer ...
```

After reviewing each and every 108 of them (!!) I decided they were all false positives as they all originate from files that are essentially Window files with an otherwise checked clean bill of health.

So I whitelisted the corresponding folders with clamTK. I tried using the whilelist functionality... but that did not work as every scan produces exactly the same false positive.

Any pointers welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a bit of time later later....I got to :

```
$ clamscan --detect-pua -i -r /home/user \ 
--exclude-dir=.thunderbird \
--exclude-dir=.mozilla-thunderbird \
--exclude-dir=.evolution \
--exclude-dir=Mail \
--exclude-dir=kmail \
--exclude-dir=/home/user/.clamtk/viruses \
--exclude-dir=/home/user/Library/Software/Windows \
--exclude-dir=/home/user/Library/Software/Android \
--log="/home/user/.clamtk/history/$(date +\%Y\%m\%d).log" 2>/dev/null
```

and it works. As it turns out I had a syntax problem.

If you are going to use this type of log file with datestamp in the name, do not forget to escape the `%` in the format piece. Also think that yr `~/.clamtk/history/` directory will eventually fill up if you don't do regular housekeeping.